# Run metacity without gnome-shell (gnome 3)

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, gdm, metacity

Hi how can i use metacity with composite manager without gnome-shell. I'm trying to do so in my custom xsession

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"; then
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`
fi

metacity --replace ccp & wmpid=$!
xsetroot -solid white &
sleep 1
if [ -f ~/.metacity-session ]; then
source ~/.metacity-session &
else
xterm &
fi
# Wait for WM
wait $wmpid
```

But I've got this in my ~/.xsession_errors

```
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j/ssh
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j/ssh
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/rumkin/keyring-Ar8I4j/gpg:0:1
Initializing tracker-miner-fs...
Tracker-Message: Setting up monitor for changes to config file:'/home/rumkin/.config/tracker/tracker-miner-fs.cfg'
Starting log:
  File:'/home/rumkin/.local/share/tracker/tracker-miner-fs.log'
Initializing tracker-store...
Tracker-Message: Setting up monitor for changes to config file:'/home/rumkin/.config/tracker/tracker-store.cfg'
Tracker-Message: Setting up monitor for changes to config file:'/home/rumkin/.config/tracker/tracker-store.cfg'
Starting log:
  File:'/home/rumkin/.local/share/tracker/tracker-store.log'

(tracker-store:7825): Tracker-CRITICAL **: D-Bus service name:'org.freedesktop.Tracker1' is already taken, perhaps the daemon is already running?
Failed to play sound: File or data not found

** (gnome-screensaver:7804): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-application-handlers

** (gnome-screensaver:7804): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-command-line

** (gnome-screensaver:7804): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-log-out

** (gnome-screensaver:7804): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-print-setup

** (gnome-screensaver:7804): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-printing

** (gnome-screensaver:7804): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-save-to-disk

** (seapplet:7809): WARNING **: Error showing notification: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `org.freedesktop.Notifications' on object at path /org/freedesktop/Notifications
Starting Dropbox...** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
Done!

(gnome-shell:7796): folks-WARNING **: Failed to find primary PersonaStore with type ID 'eds' and ID 'system'.
Individuals will not be linked properly and creating new links between Personas will not work.
The configured primary PersonaStore's backend may not be installed. If you are unsure, check with your distribution.
** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus the no_focus_window with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
** Message: Stopping applet secret agent because GNOME Shell appeared
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 1.4.0

(rhythmbox:8172): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_uint: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_UINT (value)' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_raise: assertion `!window->override_redirect' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_window_focus: assertion `!window->override_redirect' failed

(rhythmbox:8172): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_uint: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_UINT (value)' failed
[8304:8329:0212/111557:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(608)] Failed to get name owner. Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name
[8304:8329:0212/111557:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(608)] Failed to get name owner. Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2800051 (linux - Ho)
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2800051 (linux - Ho)
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
[8304:8304:0212/111558:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(513)] Failed to call method: org.chromium.Mtpd.EnumerateStorage: object_path= /org/chromium/Mtpd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.chromium.Mtpd was not provided by any .service files
Created new window in existing browser session.

(rhythmbox:8172): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_uint: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_UINT (value)' failed
```

Run on Fedora 17. What i've missed?

Answer (score 1):

Put it last in `~/.xinitrc` (with no `&`). However, as it was not intended to be used like that, to kill it, you must use `pkill -9 metacity` or shut down your computer. (Other than that, it works great; I used it like that on my Debian for ages until I found OpenBox.) But no worry, you could make an alias of the `pkill` command if you habitually wish to return to the console; and, there is no harm terminating Metacity like that.